# $x, y, z$ for dimensions

Tags: notation

We tend to use $x$ for an arbitary first dimension, $y$ for one at right angles to it, $z$ for one at rigth angles to both of *those* ... what is the letter for $4\textrm{D}$?

Comment: Often, after $x,y,z$ come $u,v,w$ ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the letter $t$, because the fourth dimension is (usually) $\textrm{time}$ which is often symbolized with $t$. However when people use many dimensions they often use the notation $x_1, x_2, ...$ since it is easier than having to remember which letter corresponds to which dimension.

Answer (score 2):

While $t$ is used in special contexts like [Minkowski space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_space) (often associated with physics) where we might want to distinguish one dimension versus the others, I find that $w$ is more common and more neutral as a next letter.

For examples in programming, see [here](https://vvvv.org/documentation/xyzw-(4d-xyz)) and [here](https://community.khronos.org/t/x-y-z-and-w/18360) and [the 4D vector page on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/4D_vector).

For examples of the pattern $(x,y,z,w)$ in various math contexts, see these MathSE questions [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/480069/26369) (a quadruple integral) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/430554/26369) (a diophantine equation in four variables) and [this Socratic question](https://socratic.org/questions/given-the-following-system-x-2-y-2-z-2-w-2-2-x-2y-z-2-3w-2-1-how-do-i-show-that-) (solving a system of equations in four variables).

Relatedly, in complex analysis there is often a convention of using $z$ to denote the complex number $x+iy$. Then $w$ is the next letter, used for another complex number which may be written $u+iv$. This can be found in, say, "[Visual Complex Analysis](https://books.google.com/books/about/Visual_Complex_Analysis.html?id=ogz5FjmiqlQC)" by Needham.

Comment: Interesting. :)