# If $w^2+x^2+y^2=z^2$ , then $z$ is even if and only if $w$ , $x$ , and $y$ are even

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

Problem:

> Suppose that $w^2+x^2+y^2=z^2$, where $w$, $x$, $y$, and $z$ always denote positive integers.
> (Hint: It may be helpful to represent even integers as $2i$ and odd integers as $2j+1$, where $i$ and $j$ are integers)
>
> Prove the proposition: $z$ is even if and only if $w$, $x$, and $y$ are even. Do this by considering all the cases of $w$, $x$, $y$ being odd or even.

The [accepted solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/430554/if-w2-x2-y2-z2-then-z-is-even-if-and-only-if-w-x-and-y-ar):

> In fact, it is easy to see that the converse holds as well. That is, for any integer $m$,
>
> $m$ is even $\iff m^2$ is a multiple of 4,
>
> $m$ is odd $\iff m^2$ is one more than a multiple of 4.

My understanding:

If $m$ is even, then $m^2$ is a multiple of 4, does not always mean: if $m^2$ is a multiple of 4, then $m$ is even.

With
$w = 2$, $x = 4$, $z = 6$:

$$z^2=2^2+4^2+6^2=4+16+36=56$$

$z=\sqrt{56}\approx 7.48$ which is not an even integer. I would like to understand the accepted solution.

Comment: The accepted solution implicitly says "Assuming we have a solution quadruple of positive integers such that ....", which contradicts your "counterexample" because $z$ is not a positive integer.

Comment: Notice your quoted piece of the solution says "for any integer $m$". So the claim $m^2$ is a multiple of 4 $\Rightarrow$ $m$ is even is talking about cases where $m$ is an integer and $m^2$ is a multiple of 4, but says nothing at all about cases where $m^2$ is a multiple of 4 but $m$ isn't actually an integer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the problem the following is stated: "where $w$, $x$, $y$, and $z$ always denote positive integers". This means that you should be ignoring all cases where $z$ isn't a positive integer, such as the example you've given.

Comment: I understand, thanks for the response.